# SQL Syntax Error Exception: ORA-00928: palavra-chave SELECT não encontrada

Tags: sql, oracle

Estou com esta mensagem ao tentar executar uma *Stored Procedure* criada no Oracle:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00928: palavra-chave SELECT não
>   encontrada
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447) at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396) at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951) at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513) at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227) at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531) at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:205)
>   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1043)
>   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
>   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
>   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3714)
>   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4755)
>   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1378)
>   at unidade3.ClienteApp.inserirSP(ClienteApp.java:71) at
>   unidade3.ClienteApp.main(ClienteApp.java:192)

---

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_INSERIRCLIENTE 
(
  CPF IN INTEGER 
, NOME IN VARCHAR2 
, EMAIL IN VARCHAR2 
) AS 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES(CPF, NOME, EMAIL);
END SP_INSERIRCLIENTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que no seu caso a solução é simples:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_INSERIRCLIENTE 
(
        CPF     IN INTEGER
    ,   NOME    IN VARCHAR2
    ,   EMAIL   IN VARCHAR2 
) IS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES(CPF, NOME, EMAIL);
END;
/
```

Comment: Bom dia pessoal! Continua o mesmo erro.

Comment: A procedure é criada ? O erro ocorre na chamada do Java ?